# Magetno 2 What happen with App, when we put the site down

Tags: magento2, websites, setup-di-compile, maintenance, app

I have live site and mobile App and I need to upload one module on site.

What happen with the mobile App, when I upgrade and compile magento site.

**Is mobile app will work at the same time when compilation is in process?**

**Is mobile app will work in maintenance mode?**

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Is mobile app will work at the same time when compilation is in process?

Ans : No, you can't access the app at the time of compilation. It gives you error.

2. Is mobile app will work in maintenance mode?

Ans : In this also you cant access the website, but in maintenance mode it wont give you error. It give you the message the site is under maintenance.

But, it always suggested to compile under maintenance mode.
```